# xcode 7.1 build/run error for iphone 4s version 9.1

Tags: ios

My app work perfectly on iPad with iOS 9.1 and all the views work perfectly in iPhone with iOS 9.1 expect one view .
With iphone 4s , 5 the problem is (lldb) with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 2 ,)
With iphone 5s , 6 , 6 plus , 6s , 6s plus no error message but the simulators hung all the time with max cpu and ram usage.

note : the implementation of view that causes the problem the same with iPad but in iPad work perfectly .

Please what the true analysis for the problem ?

Comment: If you want your problem solved asap, provide as more details as you can.

Comment: file:///Users/GNR/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/397D5698-0BE1-4678-80FC-EBD94AA74F07/data/Containers/Data/Application/659E16E6-798B-44ED-9F22-C2A068DDD390/Library/Cookies/com.ctspace.flmobile3.binarycookies
2015-11-18 17:45:11.514 FLMobile[4366:161193] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7b022fa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: This is what error I am getting while running on the Simulator and phone4 with latest version 9.1.

Comment: It seems like you have `IBOutlet` in your interface builder (.nib) file that's not connected to the class. Check your nib file, connect or delete the orphan iboutlet.

Comment: I think just clear all the derive data.. Reset the phone simulators and try again

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by investigating for 1 day. I need to change the package identifier for ex in my case com.pkg1.pkg2 and then last identifier and you need to select proper team. So that it will work I will send you the screenshot for the same.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time and answering my question.